# Can I view my not so recently opened projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, I know I can view my recently opened projects on both the Start Page, and under *Recent Projects and Solutions* on the File menu.

Is there any way to view a more comprehensive history? I am trying to find something I created as a throwaway project, and therefore was never checked into Source control (and never named properly!), but I know when I last had it open.

I know it's between ConsoleApplication1 and ConsoleApplication972, but I would rather not have to go through them all, one by one.

Thanks

Comment: I think you already know the answer: No.

Comment: Can't you just search the file contents?

Comment: It's probably not managed by VS, but it's a native feature in Windows. Recent documents are stored somewhere in the registry, and there is a fixed limit for them IIRC.

Comment: Open the directory and do a search: `datemodified:mm/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the **.suo** file get's updated every time you open a solution, even if you don't change anything.

I did a search of my source code directory for ***.suo**, and then sorted by date (descending). This allowed me to see a comprehensive list of what solutions I have had open recently, in what order.